# Upload youtube video to JW Player

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to show a YouTube video in my app using JW.player, but nothing happen when I press play. I can see the `UIWebView` in my `viewcontroller`, but the video doesn't appear how come?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    htmlPlayerWebView =[ [UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 51, 674,381)];
    [self.view addSubview:htmlPlayerWebView];
}

-(void)loadVideo
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"home" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString *HTMLString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [htmlPlayerWebView loadHTMLString:HTMLString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
}
```

And the HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/NwqHmnPBEeORiiIACmOLpg.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='playerNtFziJDGyTtg'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        jwplayer('playerNtFziJDGyTtg').setup({
            file: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ac7KhViaVqc',
            title: 'Sintel | first official trailer US (2010) 3D open movie project',
            width: '360',
            height: '640',
            fallback: 'false'
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you added a [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) to monitor the view and any errors?

Comment: Yes i have and i have no errors. The webview appear but there is nothing in it.

Comment: Also, have you seen this SO link [trying-to-implement-jw-player-on-ios?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005762/trying-to-implement-jw-player-on-ios?) Could this be the problem?

Comment: Ok, it doesn't load but are you getting delegate feedback and, more specifically, does the delegate method `webView:didFailLoadWithError:` not indicate that there are load issues? If not, it would appear that youtr URL is not being loaded.

Comment: I get no response. i've tested it is something wrong with the objective-c part. the html file works fine. it adds the UIWebView, but does not load the file.

Comment: Can you give a brief on what you've tried?

Comment: i did not fix this issue, but i added a UIWebView from storyboard and it worked like a charm.